# PHP: Glob, Wildcards - Displaying a file (video) in PHP containing a number

Tags: php, wildcard, glob

As part of a PHP script I am trying to display a (video) file from a directory containing lots of files. These files have a timestamp, the number (from a GET) and some more letters and numbers, like this: 123456-user00001[2013.09.09-12:10].h264. Basically the GET result has the number (eg. 123456), and the timestamp and other text and numbers change.

Here's the route I've been attempting:

```
if($_GET['number'] = intval($_GET['number'])) {
foreach (glob($_GET['number'] . "-user*-*:*.*") as $filename) {
echo "<h3>Files for Download</h3>";
echo "Download: <a href=\"Files/" . $filename.  "\">" . $filename . "</a><br />";
}
}
```

However, nothing appears to display, whichever way round I try the wildcards. Also, I'm not entirely sure this is the best way to have a specific file displayed, or is it?

My guess is it's the way I'm using the wildcards, but no amount of reshuffling seems to have worked.

Comment: are you sure you are globbing in the right directory? The href points to "Files/" for example. Try it with just the wildcard * after your input.

Comment: Also `if($_GET[...]=intval(...))` should be `if($_GET[...]==intval(...))`

Comment: @Passerby - i think one could just always use the inval() return and not do the compare at all. But yes, right now it will check if the return of intval() was succesfully assigned to the $_GET variable, which it will

Comment: Oh my goodness @x29a - you are quite right. Was globbing in the wrong directory! You wouldn't believe how long I spent tinkering with everything, and just didn't notice at all! Thanks for setting me right!

Comment: @x29a Except that `intval()` always return a number no matter what, so if `$_GET[...]` is not a valid number (or "0") that `intval`ed to `0`, `if` will see that as false.

Comment: @Passerby only when you not change the = to == ;) And still, its pretty ugly to rely on this, id consider assigning the value in any case and check for > 0 (if that is the desired range).